# How to compere 2 arrays of objects and get the changed array object

Tags: arrays, arrayobject

I have 2 arrays of objects. One is the old array and the other is new. What i want as the output is an array of all the elements of which any of the properties has changed, when the old and new arrays are compared. It should work for any property an object might have, not restricted to the 3 that is given. U need not handle nested objects though.

```
let old = [
    {
      id: "f4101804-a587-4420-97d3-5691a93c9143",
      name: "Mice",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c",
      name: "acooer",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716",
      name: "Yhgg",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "01381e2c-ee25-4461-93cb-d54c812551e9",
      name: "anix",
      price: "25"
    }
  ];

  let new = [
    {
      id: "f4101804-a587-4420-97d3-5691a93c9143",
      name: "Mice",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c",
      name: "acoo",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716",
      name: "Yhgg",
      price: "26"
    },
    {
      id: "01381e2c-ee25-4461-93cb-d54c812551e9",
      name: "anix",
      price: "25"
    }
  ];
```

In the given example the name property of the second element and the price property of the 3rd element has changed. So the output should be

```
[
  {
    id: '132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c',
    name: 'acoo',
    price: '25'
  },
  {
    id: 'b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716',
    name: 'Yhgg',
    price: '26'
  }
]
```

i tried this but whn i change the position of object it is considering as change in object.

```
import "./styles.css";

const a = [
  {
    id: "f4101804-a587-4420-97d3-5691a93c9143",
    name: "Mice",
    price: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c",
    name: "acooer",
    price: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716",
    name: "Yhgg",
    price: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "01381e2c-ee25-4461-93cb-d54c812551e9",
    name: "anix",
    price: "25"
  }
];
const b = [
  {
    id: "f4101804-a587-4420-97d3-5691a93c9143",
    name: "Mice",
    price: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c",
    name: "acoo",
    price: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716",
    name: "Yhgg",
    price: "26"
  },
  {
    id: "01381e2c-ee25-4461-93cb-d54c812551e9",
    name: "anixx",
    price: "25"
  }
];
let result = b.filter(
  (elm) => !a.map((elm) => JSON.stringify(elm)).includes(JSON.stringify(elm))
);
console.log(result);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

Comment: On SO, it is customary to ask for help on the code you wrote, not to ask for help writing the code. Please edit the question to show an attempted solution.

Comment: i did code almost everything. but  whn i change the position of object it is considering as change in object.

the solution is there in the link see

Answer (score 0):

The OP's filter predicate has a few errors, including using the same dummy parameter `elm` (hiding the filter's param), and testing a `map` which returns an array instead of a `find`.

Here's an improved predicate:

```
let result = b.filter(bElement => {
  return !a.find(aElement => isEquivalent(aElement, bElement))
});
```

Note a few things:

- dummy params are named to match the array they come from
- return `!a.find` returns false for a found thing, true otherwise
- equivalence is factored out, so it can be handled as it's own problem

The OP attempts to use a common equivalence test, comparing string representations, whether `JSON.stringify(someObjectA) === JSON.stringify(someObjectB)`, but this approach has drawbacks.

One is that both strings must be built before any comparison happens. What if the objects are huge, but different in every key? This could be tested before creating (and then discarding) two huge strings.

Another drawback has to do with the potential for different implementations of JS to produce different key order in `stringify`. While most implementations produce the same string, the key order isn't guaranteed by the language (as far as I know).

The snippet below contains two alternatives for equivalence: `isEquivalent_0()` uses the ill-advised stringify test. `isEquivalent_1()` does a shallow test of values. It bails as soon as if finds a key or value mismatch, and creates no intermediate (garbage) objects.

```js
const a = aData();
const b = bData();

// this equivalence compares string representation of objects
function isEquivalent_0(objA, objB) {
  return JSON.stringify(objA) === JSON.stringify(objB)
}

// this shallow equivalence checks keys and values, and terminates
// as soon as a mismatch is found
function isEquivalent_1(objA, objB) {
  for (aKey in objA) {
    if (!(aKey in objB)) return false;
    if (objA[aKey] !== objB[aKey]) return false;
  }
  for (bKey in objB) {
    if (!(bKey in objA)) return false;
    if (objA[aKey] !== objB[aKey]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

let result = b.filter(bElement => {
  return !a.find(aElement => isEquivalent_1(aElement, bElement))
});

console.log(result);

function aData() {
  return [{
      id: "f4101804-a587-4420-97d3-5691a93c9143",
      name: "Mice",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c",
      name: "acooer",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716",
      name: "Yhgg",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "01381e2c-ee25-4461-93cb-d54c812551e9",
      name: "anix",
      price: "25"
    }
  ];
}

function bData() {
  return [{
      id: "f4101804-a587-4420-97d3-5691a93c9143",
      name: "Mice",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "132a5f3b-7350-44e6-8ac8-3ba1b558ff1c",
      name: "acoo",
      price: "25"
    },
    {
      id: "b1cf9e9d-e712-4624-b754-fb9c48a75716",
      name: "Yhgg",
      price: "26"
    },
    {
      id: "01381e2c-ee25-4461-93cb-d54c812551e9",
      name: "anix",
      price: "25"
    }
  ];
}
```